# JNI - jByteArray to cli::array

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I am working with JNI for the first time, and am trying to pass a byte array from a Java applet to a C# DLL through a C++ JNI assembly.

The JNI signature...

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyApplet_invokeManager(JNIEnv *jniEnvPtr, jobject javaObj, jbyteArray encodedData)
```

The call to the C# DLL...

```
myManager->ShowQueue(encodedData);
```

The error message...

```
error C2664: 'MyModule::JNIToManaged::ShowQueue' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'jbyteArray' to 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^'   C:\Development\CrystalClient\CrystalPrintJNI\CrystalPrintJNI\CrystalPrintJNI.cpp
```

Do I need to loop through the jByteArray and store the bytes into a new array? Can someone provide some guidance please? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is C++? Or is it this abusive thing that Microsoft did to C++ to make it compatible with .NET?

Comment: The JNI signature was created automatically using 'javah' on a native java method. Check out this tutorial - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13093/C-method-calls-within-a-Java-program

Comment: Your C++ code can handle the pointer.  If you want to pass it on to C# code in a friendly way then you really do have to copy the array.

Comment: I asked another similar question here. I have converted the jbyteArray to a char* array, but I'm not sure how to get it into a cli::array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764638/jni-cannot-convert-from-char-to-cliarraytype-dimension